# Sort NSFetchedResultsController By Relationship Property? NSFetchRequest NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

As shown in the images below, a `Company` object has a relationship to a set of `FinancialMetric` objects.  I want to sort my `NSFetchedResultsController` of `Company` objects by the value of one of the specific `FinancialMetrics`
 (`value` with most recent `date` and of `type` "revenue") in the relationship property `financialMetrics`. Is this possible to do without loading the `Company` objects into an array and then sorting the array?  I would like to keep everything in the `NSFetchedResultsController` just as you would if you were sorting by any of the regular attributes like `name` or `city`.

Company Entity Details...

[image: DataModelImage1]

FinancialMetric Entity Details...

[image: DataModelImage2]

Comment: Is the Company-FinancialMetrics relationship one-one, one-many, or many-many?  And do you need your results to be grouped into sections?

Comment: The Company to FinancialMetrics relationship is one to many.  Results will not be grouped.  Just sorted in descending order by revenue value.

Comment: This will be very difficult, because of the one-many relationship, and the need to select the value with the most recent date.  I think it might be easier to maintain an additional `mostRecentValue` attribute in `Company`.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I was hoping to avoid adding an attribute just to be used for sorting.

Comment: I think there may be a way which involves fetching first to get an array of FinancialMetrics (the most recent for each company).  And then passing that array as an IN predicate to the FRC.  The FRC will also fetch FinancialMetrics, so can sort on their value, but it's straight forward to get to the Company since that is a to-one relationship.  Downside is you will have to reperform both fetches if a FinancialMetric object changes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort by the value of a to-many relationship. A sort descriptor cannot filter at the same time.

Another potential issue with your requirement is that you would have to do additional accounting to assure, for example, that the same metric type is not repeated for the same company.

There are several approaches. One is that you keep an current value in the Company entity that you can update automatically whenever the metrics change. If you just have a handful of such cases, this is a feasible strategy.

Another approach would be to make the type you are interested in explicit in the `Metric` entity. Suppose you have 12 different metrics - it would be feasible to just name them and add them as attributes to the `Metric` entity. You could then sort by the specific metric via the to-one relationship, like `metric.revenue`.

Finally, if you really want to keep the abstraction, you could refactor your fetched results controller and have it fetch the `Metric` entity instead of the `Company`. You simply filter by `type`, sort by `value` and populate your table view cells with something like `metric.company.name` instead of `company.name`.